# CMake with CLion

Tags: makefile, cmake, clion

I have been using Kdevelop with a project, now im on a different laptop, and need to build the project with CLion and MinGW on Windows.

I had this makefile (works on KDevelop)

```
CC=gcc
DEPS = cmp_micris_defs.h
OBJ = cmp_micris_datos_msc.o  cmp_micris_rutinas.o  cmp_micris_UnixSocket.o     cmp_micris_cfg.o cmp_micris_db.o cmp_micris_TCP.o cmp_micris_utiles.o     cmp_micris_datos.o cmp_micris.o
LIBS = -lpthread -lmysqlclient

.PREFIXES = .c .o

.c.o:
$(CC) -std=gnu99 -c -I/home/borja/projects/micris2/proceso-micris2/proceso/     $< $(LIBS)

cmp_micris_borja: $(OBJ)
$(CC) -o $@ $(OBJ) $(LIBS)

all: cmp_micris_borja

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJ) cmp_micris_borja
```

But CLion use Cmake to build, i have not used it before, **what should i write in CMakeLists.txt to build like before with my makefile ?**

Thanks.

Comment: Note that CLion comes with a powerful GUI that allows you to set many parameters for your build without having to write CMake code yourself. All changes made through the GUI will get applied to the underlying `CMakeLists.txt` file. This actually makes a pretty powerful way of learning CMake: Make a change in the GUI and see what the effects on the underlying CMake code are.

Comment: There are also several tutorials available on the cmake website http://www.cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/